# Creating Android Application variants that use different property value

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have two properties I am reading from a property file in my Android library e.g.

```
testURL=http://mytesturl.com
prodURL=http://myprodurl.com
```

This library is used by my Android App. I would like to build two variants of the Android app - one for test and one for Production. The only difference between the two variants is which URL to use e.g.

```
if(some_condition) 
    url=  testURL
else
    url= prodURL
```

I know the android-library plugin does not support productFlavor / buildTypes yet so I am wondering how to do this?

Comment: The if statement is in the library? or in the app?

Comment: I would like the "if" statement to be in the library but if that's not possible in the app is fine

Answer (score 1):

How about overwriting your ressource file ?

You put a default URL in your library
and create two different Application one for test and one for prod and you overwrite the ressource file with the correct value in each application. That's what I use for application branding depending on the customer, not sure it's the best solution in your case but it works.

Other solution : put a static constant TEST in you application  and check wether you're in Test mode or not.